# page method isnt working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to use a page method in my asp .net project but I don't know why it isn't working.

Basically I have 2 pages: locations.aspx and details.aspx.

In locations.aspx when I click on an image a JS function runs which calls a page method.  Then in that page method I store a session value which I use in Details.aspx page.  For some reason the page method is failing and I am getting an alert (I have set an alert in the onFailed() method).  Please tell me if there is anything wrong or if I should take any procedure.

What I have already tested:

1. The onclick event is happening.
2. If I manually put a value for session variable then it is working in Details.aspx page.

Location.aspx

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

            <img class="..." src="...." usemap="#panchagarh-map" />
                <map name="panchagarh-map">
                    <area onclick="javascript:passLocationString('Panchagarh')" href="Details.aspx" class="...." coords=" .... " shape="poly"
                </map>



        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function passLocationString(locationString) {
                PageMethods.setLocationString(locationString, onSucceeded, onFailed);
            }
            function onSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
            }
            function onFailed(error, userContext, methodName) {
                alert("An error occurred")
            }
        </script>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    </form>
```

Location.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Locations : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static void setLocationString(string temp)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["locationString"] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Details.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl parentDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
    parentDiv.ID = "test";
    parentDiv.InnerHtml = (string)Session["locationString"];

    parentDiv.Visible = true;
    Panel.Controls.Add(parentDiv);
}
```

Comment: why don't you: `alert("An error occurred: " + error);`?

Comment: i did it and it says "An error occurred[object Object]"..i dont understand it..

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see the text of error though. I would suggest to try using web service instead of page methods and see if it works. Another idea would be to check if session is configured properly in Web.config:

```
configuration>
 <system.web>
   <sessionState mode="InProc"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: so i still didnt get what the problem was..code behind page method wasnt accepting argument from javascript page method..so i found a different way..i used querry string to pass information from Locations.aspx to Details.aspx..
about querry string: 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx